# Foreign person on my github branch in xcode

Tags: xcode, github, branch

Does anyone know why I have another person's name in my XCode's branches? I didn't authorize people in my github yet.

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

You can check under your repository's Settings for Collaborators and see if someone else has committed on the branch before.

[image: Check this]

Otherwise it could've just been that you committed from another computer which has a different GitHub username. [Github documentation on usernames](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/setting-your-username-in-git)

Edit from comment:

It could alternatively be an issue with XCode where it's showing a branch from a previous repo you might've checked out. A good idea is to check on Github (or wherever you host your git repo's) and see if there are other branches there. As it could be a more "accurate" source of truth than XCode itself.

Github example image:

[image: Github Branch selection screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your response. No collaborator in the settings and I did not connect to another post. That's why I find it really weird

Comment: @YassineBADRI i updated my answer. Maybe that can guide you a bit :)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer so clearly. It's strange because it's my first repository and I just started with Xcode. I will investigate and see where this person could come from. If I have any news, I will get back to you. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It is because your project has 2 repositories. You can check it in the source code navigator as below:
[Source code navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH1Yb.png)